# Comment Templates for Parenting.SE

Tags: discussion, comments

There are many events where we may want or need to leave a comment: welcoming new users, encouraging "be nice", indicating an answer isn't really an answer, and more. It is helpful to not have to retype such comments repeatedly.

These do not define required wording, but can provide a useful central location to find (and copy) commonly used phrases. Feel free to improve phrasing in this thread (it is a community wiki post), or adjust the wording to adapt to situations when you are copying.

---

If your comment contains links and/or formatting, please include a "code block" version to speed up copying. For example:

> This is what an **example comment** and [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com) look like.

`This is what an **example comment** and [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com) look like.`

The first paragraph shows how the comment will appear, the second what [markdown symbols](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) are used to create it.

---

An additional useful reference for any users who often leave comments: [StackExchange's standard "magic links"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000)!

Comment: While I'm hoping this ends up being fairly Parenting.SE specific, here are some other sites that have similar Meta wikis: [math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates), [LaTeX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks), and [TCS](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/comment-templates).

Comment: As long as you saw my suggestions, @Erica, I'm fine with the deletion and won't bother trying to shoehorn my suggestions into comments.

Comment: @aparente001 I don't entirely understand -- do you want me to make the comments and edits for you?

Comment: I hesitate to edit your answers because I have no idea which of my suggestions, if any, feel right to you.  You have a great deal of experience using these standard answers, and you know better than I do what works well.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited to add**: D'oh! These aren't very Parenting.SE specific, sorry. :-(

I'm not exactly sure how to do this (I am tech-challenged). But I have some that I use often enough to copy & paste. (I often play with them as needed.)

Please feel free to improve the wording.

For **new users** with **Answer** problems:

> Hi and welcome. Unlike forums which encourage discussion, Parenting is a Q&A site; answers are meant to address the OP's question. This is a comment, which you can leave after earning a bit of reputation. Please see the [site tour](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help sections](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help) for more information. Thanks, and again, welcome!

`Hi and welcome. Unlike forums which encourage discussion, Parenting is a Q&A site; answers are meant to address the OP's question. This is a comment, which you can leave after earning a bit of reputation. Please see the [site tour](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help sections](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help) for more information. Thanks, and again, welcome!`

---

> Hi, X, and welcome to the site. The "Answer" section should only be used for actual answers. If you want clarification from the person who posted something, that should be done in a comment, which can be done after you've earned a small amount of reputation. Please see the [site tour](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help sections](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help) for more information. Thanks.

`Hi, X, and welcome to the site. The "Answer" section should only be used for actual answers. If you want clarification from the person who posted something, that should be done in a comment, which can be done after you've earned a small amount of reputation. Please see the [site tour](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help sections](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help) for more information. Thanks.`

---

> Hi, and welcome to Parenting.SE! Unlike discussion forums, "Answers"  are meant to address the original question only. We welcome new questions; please feel free to post your question by [asking a new question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). That way, you'll get helpful answers, which won't happen here. Again, welcome!

`Hi, and welcome to Parenting.SE! Unlike discussion forums, "Answers"  are meant to address the original question only. We welcome new questions; please feel free to post your question by [asking a new question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). That way, you'll get helpful answers, which won't happen here. Again, welcome!`

For experienced users, **Not An Answer**:

> This answer [doesn't really address the OP's question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), which was "Xxx". Can you please edit to address these issues in your answer? Otherwise what may be helpful to some may be converted to a comment.

`This answer [doesn't really address the OP's question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), which was "Xxx". Can you please edit to address these issues in your answer? Otherwise what may be helpful to some may be converted to a comment.`

I'll stop here for now.

Comment: I'm splitting some of these into separate answers :)

Answer (score 1):

**Asking for sources**

For users with reputation (not new users):

1. > This is an interesting statement: "Xxxx" Could you please add a
   >   reference/source to support it? People might like to do further
   >   reading on this subject. Thanks!
2. > "Xxxx." Could you please support your claims with some sources? The SE
   >   model is for verifiable answers. While we value experience, we really
   >   appreciate references for further reading. Thanks!

Comment: I like #1 better.

Answer (score 1):

For **new users** with **question** problems:

> Hi, and welcome! Though this is an interesting question, it's more of [a discussion-type question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), which is not on topic on SE sites. Please see the [help sections](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about what questions are on-topic on the site.

`Hi, and welcome! Though this is an interesting question, it's more of [a discussion-type question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), which is not on topic on SE sites. Please see the [help sections](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about what questions are on-topic on the site. If you can edit it to make it more about parenting and more specific/on topic, please do. Thanks!`

Comment: I like it.  I would just replace "information about what topics are" by "information about what types of topics are".